# Why does the Lagrangian equal $T-V$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

When defining $L=T-V$, and using Euler-Lagrange equations ($\partial_x L = \frac{d}{dt} \partial_{\dot{x}} L$), we get back $m \ddot{x} = - \frac{dV}{dx}$ **ONLY WHEN ASSUMING** that $V(x, \dot{x}) = V(x)$ and $T(x, \dot{x}) = T(\dot{x})$.

However, these assumtions aren't always true (if I'm not mistaken, it may be the case in the electromagnetic potential).

Thus, my question is : why is $L=T-V$ even when those assumptions break?

Comment: Because what doesn't go in the Lagrangian through the potential, i.e. the non-conservative actions, can be represented as generalized forces

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Best [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1147) imho on that subject.

Comment: Indeed those assumptions are not always applicable, and when they aren't Hamilton's action is not applicable. A necessary condition is that there is a well-defined potential energy. In order to have a well-defined potential energy: the force that is involved must be a conservative force, and generalized coordinates, when used, must be holonomic. In classical mechanics: when those conditions are met: $L=T-V$. To understand why for classical mechanics $L=T-V$ see my discussion of [Hamilton's stationary action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/670705/17198). (Demonstration with diagrams)