# Deriving Lagrange equation with constraint

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

I'm having a hard time understanding the derivation of Lagrange equation from Newton's law when there is constraint (I'm ok with the basic case where there is only kinetic energy and potential function; I don't want to take least action principle to be the fundamental axiom). Many books use either virtual work (which I <s>can't make sense of</s> am still trying to translate into differential) or some obscure analysis on manifold (which I'm not well-versed in). I saw a proof in these Classical Mechanics [notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics.html) by Tong. It is short but still very confusing to me. Why does (2.33) in the following screenshot give the equations for motion of $x^A$? They are Euler-Lagrange equations for $L'$, which is just some "random" Lagrangian that he writes down; why does $L'$ have any physical meaning?

[image]

Comment: You mention 'trying to translate the concept of virtual work into differential'. I assume you want that for the purpose of deriving the Lagrange equation from Newton's first law. The following may be of use to you: there is a way to proceed from Newton's first law to the Lagrange equation using the concept of *work* (rather than using the concept of virtual work). It consists of using the Work-Energy theorem as intermediary. There is an answer by me that includes a [derivation of the work-energy theorem using differentials](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/670705/17198)

Answer (score 1):

1. In Ref. 1 the [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle) (SAP) for the old action $S~=~\int\! dt~L$ is treated as a first principle, so the new SAP $S^{\prime}~=~\int\! dt~ L^{\prime}$ in eq. (2.31) follows from the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).
2. Alternatively, in Ref 2. [d'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) (DAP) leads to
   [Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics)
   $$ \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^j}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^j}~=~Q_j, \qquad j~\in \{1,\ldots, n\}. \tag{A}$$
   A [holonomic constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) $f(q,t)=0$ now has a [generalized constraint force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_forces)
   $$ Q_j~=~\lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^j}\tag{B}$$
   proportional to the gradient of the constraint function $f$. The Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ is the proportionality factor. Such reasoning leads to eq. (2.33) in Ref. 1.

References:

1. D. Tong, [*Lectures on Classical Dynamics*](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics.html).
2. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* chapter 1.