# Maximum aging and path of rock

Tags: general-relativity, variational-principle, boundary-conditions, geodesics

When a rock falls from a ledge, why does it head to the surface and not up to where time runs faster?

If a rock, free from forces, follows a worldline of maximum aging, why would that rock approach Earth where the rate of time runs slower, and so would slow down the rocks aging? Shouldn’t the rock avoid earth?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38348/2451

Comment: This explains it brilliantly: http://www.science20.com/hammock_physicist/principle_maximal_aging#comments

Answer (score 2):

A rising trajectory is a geodesic. A falling trajectory is a geodesic. The principle of maximum aging doesn't select one geodesic over other geodesics. It tells us which world-lines are geodesics and which ones aren't. Given two spacetime events A and B, there is typically exactly one geodesic connecting them. In your example, you've only specified A, not B.