# If the path integral formulation includes future events, why doesn't that imply retrocausality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, boundary-conditions, causality

I know that such events would cancel out in the math, but if an extreme event were to happen in the future (say a black hole forming or something on that par), would a particle in the present react to it? If not, why?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38348/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path integral is a broad idea, which comes in several different flavors. In non-relativistic quantum mechanics for one particle, you calculate the propagator matrix element $\langle {\bf x}_f| U(t_f,t_i) | {\bf x}_i \rangle$ by summing $\exp(i\, S[{\bf x}(t)]\, /\hbar)$ over paths connecting $(t_i, {\bf x}_i)$ to $(t_f, {\bf x}_f)$ which travel forward in time, so there's clearly no retrocausality. In relativistic quantum field theory, you typically use the LSZ formalism, which involves integrating $\exp(i S[\varphi(x)] / \hbar)$ with $S[\varphi(x)] := \int_{t_i}^{t_f} dt\, \int d^3 {\bf x}\, \mathcal{L}(\varphi(x), \partial_\mu \varphi(x); x)$ in the limit $t_i \to -\infty$ and $t_f \to +\infty$, so that the incoming and outgoing particles are thought of as far-separated and asymptotically noninteracting. (In practice, this limit is carried out through the use of the "$i\epsilon$ trick" in the denominator of the propagator, which sets the boundary conditions.) In neither case are paths that extend later than $t_f$ considered, so there is no retrocausality. (You do find acausal correlations across spacelike separations, but they cannot transmit acausal influences.)

Comment: *"You do find acausal correlations across spacelike separations, but they cannot transmit acausal influences."* Cool! Where could someone read about that?

Comment: @DanielSank Considering scalar field theory for simplicity: the precise statement is that unlike commutators of quantum fields, the Feynman propagator, which is the Green's function for the Klein-Gordon equation with the boundary conditions relevant for calculating correlation functions in relativistic QFT (an implicit $+i \epsilon $ in the denominator with $\epsilon \to 0^+$), does not vanish over spacelike separations, although it turns out to decay exponentially quickly with proper distance.

Comment: @DanielSank This is why people say that at a given instant, the ground state of a relativistic QFT is spatially entangled: $\langle \varphi(x) \varphi(y) \rangle - \langle \varphi(x) \rangle \langle \varphi(y) \rangle \neq 0$ for spacelike separated $x$ and $y$. But it turns out that it's the expectation value of the *commutator* of fields, not the simple product, that determines whether causal influences can be transmitted, and this expectation value *is* zero for spacelike separations. The correlations are the usual EPR/Bell's theorem type correlations that can't be used to communicate.

Comment: @DanielSank  I think is discussed in most QFT books when they derive the Feynman propagator.

Comment: That is bonkers. Thanks for the clear and concise explanation.